# ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE on samsung device blurred

Tags: android, android-camera, samsung-mobile

I'm using this code to open camera intent :

```
Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);
```

And it works fine but only on Samsung devices (8\9) with android 8
after I take a picture the preview is all blurry , 
anyone got that weird behavior ?

( I also tried without the putExtra line )

Here are the screenshots :

[image: before]

[image: after[![][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCe6z.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to give a photo path Uri as an extra in the camera intent as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), mUserID + ".jpg");
Uri photoPath = getUriForFile(mContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, file);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoPath);   //--> here 
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
```

then,  you can get the captured image in that Uri itself in onActivityResult

Comment: Is that why the preview looks smooshed ? because it's thumbnailed ? also why only samsung?

Comment: yes it is because you are only getting the thumbnail. I'm sure its happening in other devices too.

Comment: this was the correct answer , just needed to implement the fileprovider and was good to go